# Matlab Convolution regarding the conv() function and length()/size() function

Tags: matlab, convolution

I'm kind've new to Matlab and stack overflow to begin with, so if I do something wrong outside of the guidelines, please don't hesitate to point it out. Thanks!

I have been trying to do convolution between two functions and I have been having a hard time trying to get it to work.

```
t=0:.01:10;        
h=exp(-t);        
x=zeros(size(t));   % When I used length(t), I would get an error that says in conv(), A and B must be vectors.    
x(1)=2;        
x(4)=5;         
y=conv(h,x);         
figure; subplot(3,1,1);plot(t,x);   % The discrete function would not show (at x=1 and x=4)     
subplot(3,1,2);plot(t,h);        
subplot(3,1,3);plot(t,y(1:length(t)));    %Nothing is plotted here when ran
```

I commented my issues with the code. I don't understand the difference of `length` and `size` in this case and how it would make a difference.

For the  second comment, `x=1` should have an amplitude of `2`. While `x=4` should have an amplitude of `5`. When plotted, it only shows nothing in the locations specified but looks jumbled up at `x=0`. I'm assuming that's the reason why the convoluted plot won't be displayed.

The original problem statement is given if it helps to understand what I was thinking throughout.

> Consider an input signal x(t) that consists of two delta functions at t = 1 and t = 4 with amplitudes A1 = 5 and A2 = 2, respectively, to a linear system with impulse response h that is an exponential pulse (h(t) = e ^−t ). Plot x(t), h(t) and the output of the linear system y(t) for t in the range of 0 to 10 using increments of 0.01. Use the MATLAB built-in function conv.

Answer (score 0):

**The initial question regarding `size` vs `length`**

`length` yields a scalar that is equal to the largest dimension of the input. In the case of your array, the `size` is `1 x N`, so `length` yields `N`.

```
size(t)
%   1   1001

length(t)
%   1001
```

If you pass a scalar (`N`) to `ones`, `zeros`, or a similar function, it will create a *square matrix* that is `N x N`. This results in the error that you see when using `conv` since `conv` does not accept matrix inputs.

```
size(ones(length(t)))
%   1001    1001
```

When you pass a vector to `ones` or `zeros`, the output will be *that size* so since `size` returns a vector (as shown above), the output is the same size (and a vector) so `conv` does not have any issues

```
size(ones(size(t)))
%   1   1001
```

If you want a vector, you need to explicitly specify the number of rows and columns. Also, in my opinion, it's better to use `numel` to the number of elements in a vector as it's less ambiguous than `length`

```
z = zeros(1, numel(t));
```

**The second question regarding the convolution output**:

First of all, the impulses that you create are at the first and fourth *index* of `x` and not at the locations where `t = 1` and `t = 4`. Since you create `t` using  a spacing of `0.01`, `t(1)` actually corresponds to `t = 0` and `t(4)` corresponds to `t = 0.03`

You instead want to use the *value* of `t` to specify where to put your impulses

```
x(t == 1) = 2;
x(t == 4) = 5;
```

Note that due to floating point errors, you may not have *exactly* `t == 1` and `t == 4` so you can use a small epsilon instead

```
x(abs(t - 1) < eps) = 2;
x(abs(t - 4) < eps) = 5;
```

Once we make this change, we get the expected scaled and shifted versions of the input function.

[image]